# Redirect happens before form data is processed

Tags: javascript, redirecttoaction, onload-event

What i'm trying to do here is to sends an email to a salesperson notifying them that their client has viewed a google docs presentation.
The query's Num=val is a serial number that I use to get the actual google doc's url out of a database and stuff it into a form.

My problem is that the page redirects before the data is retrieved, and ends up going to the default for the site,  nitrofill.com.index

The gdform.php file has the header redirect, which works fine if I don't try to process the form when the page loads.  Heres the code:

```
<?php

$sn=$_GET['num'];
echo $sn;

mysql_connect($hostname,$username, $password) OR DIE ('Unable to connect to database! Please try again later.');
mysql_select_db($dbname);
 $selectSQL = "select * from `Presentations` where `serialnum` ='" . $sn ."'" ;

$result = mysql_query($selectSQL) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result,  MYSQL_BOTH);


?>

<script type="text/javascript">
function myfunc () {
var frm = document.getElementById("notice");
frm.submit();
}
window.onload = myfunc;
</script>

<title>Nitrofill Document</title></head>
<body>
 <form id="notice" action="http://m3sglobal.com/gdform.php" method="post"> 
  <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="<?php echo (urldecode($row['recipient'])) . " has viewed the document you sent them."; ?>" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="<?php echo ((urldecode($row['docurl']))); ?>"/>
<label>Email:</label><input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo (urldecode($row['tracker'])); ?>"/>
<label>Comments:</label><textarea name="comments" cols="40" rows="5">
Document Viewed:<?php echo ((urldecode($row['docurl']))); ?>

When Accessed:<?php echo ((urldecode($row['last_accessed']))); ?>
</textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

The gdform.php does the redirect like this:

```
  while (list ($key, $val) = each ($query_vars)) {
     fputs($fp,"<GDFORM_VARIABLE NAME=$key START>\n");
     fputs($fp,"$val\n");
     fputs($fp,"<GDFORM_VARIABLE NAME=$key END>\n");
     if ($key == "redirect") { $landing_page = $val;}
    }
    fclose($fp);
     if ($landing_page != ""){
    header("Location: "  . $landing_page);
    } else {
    header("Location: http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]."/");
    }
```

Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 0):

Code in HTML is executed top-down. You're submitting as soon as you get to that block of JavaScript, which is before you even render the form on the page.

Move your JS code to the bottom of the page, or execute it after the DOM is ready.

Comment: Yeah, that didn't do it.  For some reason, the gdform.php is no longer even getting the query string from the first page.  I broke something and haven't figured it out yet.    It looks like $query_vars is reset no matter what, which would always make this default back to the HTTP_HOST.  I tried commenting this out, and it worked ONCE.  Then it started going back to the HTTP_HOST again, even with the line commented out.

Comment: $request_method = $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];

    if($request_method == "GET"){
      $query_vars = $_GET;
    } elseif ($request_method == "POST"){
      $query_vars = $_POST;
    }
    reset($query_vars);
    $t = date("U");

Comment: I think the problem is on the server-side. Your form looks OK.